# How to create a new array from another array based on third array?

Tags: javascript

I have a `structuredFormData` array with these values:

```
[
  {
    "season": "autumn",
    "firstContactPersonName": "John",
    "firstContactPersonPhone": "46442644",
    "secondContactPersonName": "Jhonny",
    "secondContactPersonPhone": "46442644",
  },
  {
    "season": "christmas",
    "firstContactPersonName": "Tommy",
    "firstContactPersonPhone": "46442644",
    "secondContactPersonPhone": "Thomas",
  },
]
```

I have another array holding the dates, `selectedDate` array: `["autumn=2020-08-28", "christmas=2020-12-28"]`

My function creates a new array `updatedStructuredFormData` and populate the new array with data for sending to backend. Or maybe just update the existing array `structuredFormData` ?

```
let updatedStructuredFormData = structuredFormData.map(x => {
            let season = x.season;
            x.date = selectedDate.find(e => e.indexOf(season) > -1).split("=")[1];
            return x;
        });
```

The problem is, if i only select one date and the `dates` array looks like this: `["autumn=2020-08-28"]` i only want to populate these values into new array:

```
{
"season": "autumn",
"firstContactPersonName": "John",
"firstContactPersonPhone": "46442644",
"secondContactPersonName": "Jhonny",
"secondContactPersonPhone": "46442644",
}
```

I am new to JavaScript and need help how i can filter only the selected values in `dates` array.

Expected outcome should be:

```
[
    {
      "season": "autumn",
      "firstContactPersonName": "John",
      "firstContactPersonPhone": "46442644",
      "secondContactPersonName": "Jhonny",
      "secondContactPersonPhone": "46442644",
      "date": "2020-08-28"
    }
]
```

If `selectedDate` array also have an date of christmas `["autumn=28-08-28", "christmas=2020-12-28"]`, then expected outcome would be:

```
[
    {
      "season": "autumn",
      "firstContactPersonName": "John",
      "firstContactPersonPhone": "46442644",
      "secondContactPersonName": "Jhonny",
      "secondContactPersonPhone": "46442644",
      "date": "2020-08-28"
    },
    {
      "season": "christmas",
      "firstContactPersonName": "Tommy",
      "firstContactPersonPhone": "46442644",
      "date": "2020-12-28"
     }
]
```

Thank you :)

Comment: If you don’t necessarily want to map _all_ array elements to something new, then you don’t want `map` to begin with, but … `filter`.

Comment: what is the expected outcome

Comment: @brk i updated the post

Comment: I would recommend that instead of splitting your `selectedDate` elements up inside your callback function, to reduce that to an array that contains only the two string values `autumn` and `christmas` (or just `autumn`, for your second case), to begin with. Then you can use `indexOf` to determine if the `season` of your current item matches.

Comment: @CBroe , i am new to javaScript, possible for you to post an example with comments so i can understand how to do it ? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is one way to do this using `.reduce()`:

```
// Array to filter
const arr = [
  {
    season: "autumn",
    firstContactPersonName: "John",
    firstContactPersonPhone: "46442644",
    secondContactPersonName: "Jhonny",
    secondContactPersonPhone: "46442644"
  },
  {
    season: "christmas",
    firstContactPersonName: "Tommy",
    firstContactPersonPhone: "46442644",
    secondContactPersonPhone: "Thomas"
  }
];

// date to filter for
const selectedDates = ["autumn=28-08-28", "christmas=2020-12-28"];

// loop over each item and filter for season that is in "selectedDate"
const filtered = arr.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  // looping over dates to see if current items date is in the selected dates.  We also save the result to a const as we will use it to add to our final array
  const maybeDate = selectedDates.filter(date => date.includes(curr.season));

  // check if we have a date
  if (maybeDate.length > 0) {
    // extract date
    const date = maybeDate[0].split("=")[1];
    // update accumulator
    acc = [...acc, { ...curr, date }];
  }

  return acc;
}, []);

console.log({ filtered });

// results
{
  filtered:
  [{
    season: 'autumn',
    firstContactPersonName: 'John',
    firstContactPersonPhone: '46442644',
    secondContactPersonName: 'Jhonny',
    secondContactPersonPhone: '46442644',
    date: '28-08-28'
  },
  {
    season: 'christmas',
    firstContactPersonName: 'Tommy',
    firstContactPersonPhone: '46442644',
    secondContactPersonPhone: 'Thomas',
    date: '2020-12-28'
  }]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A step by step method to solving this would be to:

1. Transform selectedDate to an array of objects of season and date properties:

   ```
    const seasonDates = dates.map(d => ({
     season: d.split('=')[0],
     date:d.split('=')[1]
    }))
   ```
2. Compute `transformedStructuredFormData` with date:

   ```
   const transformedStructuredFormData = structuredFormData.map(d => {
     const time = seasonDate.filter(i => i.season === d.season)

     if (time.length) d.date = time[0].date;

     return d;
   })
   ```

   All together:

```js
const structuredFormData = [{
    "season": "autumn",
    "firstContactPersonName": "John",
    "firstContactPersonPhone": "46442644",
    "secondContactPersonName": "Jhonny",
    "secondContactPersonPhone": "46442644",
  },
  {
    "season": "christmas",
    "firstContactPersonName": "Tommy",
    "firstContactPersonPhone": "46442644",
    "secondContactPersonPhone": "Thomas",
  },
];

const selectedDate = ["autumn=2020-08-28", "christmas=2020-12-28"];

const seasonDates = selectedDate.map(d => ({
  season: d.split('=')[0],
  date: d.split('=')[1]
}));

const transformedFormData = structuredFormData.map(d => {
  const time = seasonDates.filter(i => i.season === d.season);
  
  if (time.length) d.date = time[0].date;

  return d;
});

console.log(transformedFormData)
```